# How to use azure functions to create trigger event based on files received in azure data lake store

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-function-app

I have a .csv file in Azure data lake store, can I Use a function app to trigger an Azure Data Factory (ADF) event whenever the .csv file gets loaded in the data lake store. Current ADF supports event's for blob storage but not for data lakes.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: please clarify if you are talking about Data Lake Store Gen1 or Gen2

Comment: we are using Data Lake Store Gen1

Comment: Data Lake Store Gen1 does not support to emit events when new files are created (and thus trigger anything: Functions, ADF, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

ADF pipeline can be triggered by rest API and power shell. Maybe you can use azure function to call rest API or powershell script to control ADF pipeline run.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline?view=azurermps-6.13.0